# How to add button to top left corner in UICollectionViewCell in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uicollectionviewcell

I want to add the Button to the top left corner of the cell.I have tried but i always added inside the collection view cell but not on the cell so please tell me how can i o this?

I have tried this.

```
    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BlogAlbumCell  *cell;
    static NSString *identifier = @"UserBlogAlbum";
    cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UserAlbum *user_allbum=[arr_userAlbums objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.label_blog_name.text=user_allbum.album_name;
    [cell.image_blog_image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[IMAGE_BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:user_allbum.album_image]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"post_placeholder.png"]];
    if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"longPressed"] isEqualToString:@"yes"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Inside the long press section");
        CABasicAnimation* anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
        [anim setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f]];
        [anim setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:M_PI/50]];
        [anim setDuration:0.1];
        [anim setRepeatCount:NSUIntegerMax];
        [anim setAutoreverses:YES];
        cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
        [cell.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"SpringboardShake"];
        CGFloat delButtonSize = 30;
        UIButton *delButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-5,-5, delButtonSize, delButtonSize)];
        delButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [delButton setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"cross_30.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [delButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        [cell addSubview:delButton];
        delButton.tag=indexPath.row;
        [delButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteAlbum:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    else if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"singleTap"] isEqualToString:@"yes"])
    {
        if(indexPath.row==([arr_userAlbums count]-1))
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:@"no" forKey:@"singleTap"];
        }
        for(UIView *subview in [cell subviews])
        {
            if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
            {
                [subview removeFromSuperview];
            }

        }
        [cell.layer removeAllAnimations];
        // _deleteButton.hidden = YES; 
         [_deleteButton removeFromSuperview];
    }
        return cell;
}
```

But it does not add the button to the top left.

I want like this

[image]

**EDIT:**

This is what i am getting as of now 
[image]

Comment: Where did you place those code?

Comment: in cellForItemAtIndexPath.

Comment: `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is not the best place for customizations like this, but it can work when you do it right. Please share more code, at least your complete method `cellForItemAtIndexPath` . However, I would go for a custom cell class.

Comment: check update question.@HermannKlecker

Answer (score 1):

Your design in Main.storyBoard like:

[image]

Now, create IBOutlet of Button in your custom cell.
and set properties of this button in **cellForItemAtIndexPath** method, like:

```
[cell.btnDelete setTag:indexPath.row];
[cell.btnDelete addTarget:self action:@selector(btnDeleteFolderTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and create **btnDeleteFolderTapped** method:

```
    -(void)btnDeleteFolderTapped:(id)sender
    {
         // handle your stuff here
    }
```

for space between cell, put below code in your .m file:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(IS_IPHONE_6P)
    {
        return CGSizeMake(([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 70) / 2, ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 70) / 2);
    }
    else
    {
        return CGSizeMake(([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 60) / 2, ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 60) / 2);
    }
}
```

and go to Main.storyboard, click on collectionView set properties like:

[image]

Comment: but this will create some extra space between cell from both the left & right side but i don't want to have large gap between the cells

Comment: can you suggest something better than this?See it will create extra space between cells.becuase cell is large but only it's content is small

Comment: it is only showing two cells in a row i want to show 3 cells in row with minimum constant spacing.suggest something better please it is still problem

Comment: set cell background red and check with divide by 3 in following method:-->  - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: Problem is your collectionview cell are larger and content view is small that's why this space happens between cell

Answer (score 0):

Because you add button as subview of cell, of course it will be add button in cell not on. For example your icon size is 60x60 and cell size is 80x80. Just add invisible (i mean `backgroundColor` is clear) `UIView` on that cell which size is same as cell 80x80 and add icon as subview of that view and give this frame `CGRectMake(10, 10, 60, 60)`. Then last, add icon as subview of that view too at top left corner like `CGRectMake(0, 0, delButtonSize, delButtonSize)`. Your UI hierarchy should be like this;

> UICollectionViewCell -> UIView -> Delete Button & App Icon

Comment: This won' t work because it will block the touch events on the cel & also the new view is also a subview of the main view.

Answer (score 0):

[image]I have found a simple hack for doing this. .

1.Take the image you have to show in cell smaller then the cell size and align it to right - bottom.

2. Now just add your button to the left-top at the remaining space of cell.

If you are beginner and don't know how to play with constraint then I let me explain what I actually did.

1. I made my cell 100X100 pts and imageView 70X70 pts.
2. then align given imageView right and bottom constraint to its superview with constant value "0" or ZERO.
3. Give left and top constraint constant 30 pts.
4. Add button with cross image icon.
5. left align button with imageView by giving -10 left align constraint points
6. similarly top align button with imageView -10 top align constraint points.

It will give the same user experience as required!. I have attached an image as well.